# How to autologin to a web app after I close the browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, autologin

I have done an web application in MVC4. I have a problem with the login,anytime I close the browser without pressing logout, next time I want to access the application it askes me to login. How can I do an autologin? The webapp should ask me to login only when I have pressed logout not when I have closed the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp.net membership then FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie has a parameter that specifies if the authentication cookie is permanently stored.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);
```

For more info on Form Authentication refer this link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/601687/ASP-NET-MVC-Forms-Authentication-Customized

[Form Authentication beginner](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF)

Comment: `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Email, true);
 httpCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);` 

I have this one my code but its the same. It still requires me to login with my email after I close the browser , and not pressed logout